# Component{} Unknown component. (M300)

Tags: qt, qml

qml project config file:
[image: qml project config file]

my qml file:
[image: my qml file]

qt version:
[image: qt version]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

[JarMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7427152/jarman) suggestion:

In Qt Creator main menu:

```
Tools > QML/JS > Reset Code Model
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding an addition line:

```
import QtQml 1.1
```

does trick.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to update QT Creator version. I solved similar problem with that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

you can resolve it by add "// @disable-check M300"
Like this:

```
Component { // @disable-check M300
   //code
}
```

Comment: This is not solving the problem, it's ignoring it by disabling the warning.